# Reactjs refactoring a component to a function

Tags: reactjs, function, refactoring, use-state

I am trying to convert the following Component into Function.
I need it to accept or access one parameter, do a database lookup and return a String.

I get the following compile errors implying I have incorrect syntax for a function. Any help completing the new function would be appreciated!

Errors:
src\Services\getAssetTypeNameFunction.js
Line 5:45:   React Hook "useState" is called in function "getAssetTypeNameFunction" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
Line 11:13:  'assettype' is not defined

New Function Code
...

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import AssetTypeService from './AssetTypeService'
    const getAssetTypeNameFunction = () =>{
    const [assettype_assettypeId,setData] = useState('assettype_assettypeId')
    AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(assettype_assettypeId).then( (res) =>
    {let assettype = res.data;
    });
    return (
        <ul> 
           {assettype.assettypeName}  
        </ul>
    );
}
export default getAssetTypeNameFunction;
```

...

Old Component Code that worked..
...

```
**import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AssetTypeService from '../Services/AssetTypeService'

class GetAssetTypeNameComponent extends Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props)
         this.state = {
             assettype:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(this.props.datafromparent).then( (res) =>{
            let assettype = res.data;
            this.setState({isLoading:false});
            this.setState({
                assettypeName: assettype.assettypeName,
                assettypeType: assettype.assettypeType
            });
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               {this.state.assettypeName}  
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default GetAssetTypeNameComponent;**
```

...

Answer (score 1):

```
New function code:
...

   import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
   import AssetTypeService from './AssetTypeService'
   
   function GetAssetTypeNameFunction() {
   const [assettype, setAssetType] = useState(null)
   useEffect( () => {
     AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(assettype_assettypeId).then((res) => {
       setAssetType(res.data);
     });
   }, []);
   if(!assettype)
     return (<ul>loading...</ul>)
   return (<ul>assettype.assettypeName</ul>);
   }
   export default GetAssetTypeNameFunction;

...
```

Comment: Line 7:40:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "getAssetTypeNameFunction" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Why do I get this error and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Well, changed function name to uppercase and it compiles. I get error when executing. I think because I calling the function from within an eventHandler:

editAssets(assetsid,assettype_assettypeId){
        if (GetAssetTypeNameFunction(assettype_assettypeId) === "Tower")
        {  this.props.history.push(`/add-assetstower/${assetsid}/${this.props.match.params.sitemasterid}`);
        }]
------------

Comment: Changed function name to uppercase and it compiles. I get error when executing. I think because I calling the function from within an eventHandler:

editAssets(assetsid,assettype_assettypeId){
        if (GetAssetTypeNameFunction(assettype_assettypeId) === "Tower")
        {  this.props.history.push(`/add-assetstower/${assetsid}/${this.props.match.params.sitemasterid}`);
        }]
------------
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
I am responding to a onClick in a list to route to a specific component based on the function $.

Answer (score 0):

In your Componenent you used componentDidMount to fetch data.

You could the useEffect Hook in your function to have the same effect

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

useEffect takes two parameters, a function that gets called and a dependencies array.

if you pass in an empty array into as dependencies, your function gets only called on after your function gets mounted

```js
const [assettype, setAssetType] = useState(null)
useEffect( () => {
  AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(assettype_assettypeId).then((res) => {
    setAssetType(res.data);
  });
}, [])
if(!assettype)
  return (<ul>loading...</ul>
return (<ul>assettype.assettypeName</ul>)
```

Comment: I (you)  are close. Some small syntax creating err...
Complete function code and error in original post